# haskell state monad in function and argument

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I have a question regarding the usage of the state monad if a function and its argument, that is also a function, both change the state.

here is the short info:
function `foo` changes the state
function `bar` changes the state

I want to call:

```
foo bar
```

if I call `bar` alone, the the state is set to "bar"
if I call `foo bar` then the state is only "foo" instead of "foobar", so it seems that `bar` did not change the state, and I don't understand why.

Any clarification is appreciated.

Here is the full code:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.State

main :: IO ()
main = do
  a <- execStateT test1 ""
  print a
  a <- execStateT test2 ""
  print a

type MyState = String
type MyStateMonadT = StateT MyState IO

test1 :: MyStateMonadT ()
test1 = do
  bar
  return ()

test2 :: MyStateMonadT ()
test2 = do
  foo bar
  return ()

data Foo = Foo
data Bar = Bar

foo :: MyStateMonadT Bar -> MyStateMonadT Foo
foo bar = do
  modify (++"foo")
  return Foo

bar :: MyStateMonadT Bar
bar = do
  modify (++"bar")
  return Bar
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're not actually *calling* `bar` inside `foo`.

You can do that using `_ <- bar`.

This appends `"foobar"` to the state:

```
foo :: MyStateMonadT Bar -> MyStateMonadT Foo
foo bar = do
  modify (++"foo")
  _ <- bar
  return Foo
```

and this appends `"barfoo"`:

```
foo :: MyStateMonadT Bar -> MyStateMonadT Foo
foo bar = do
  _ <- bar
  modify (++"foo")
  return Foo
```

Comment: is it an optimization in the GHC compiler?

Comment: @agreif nope. Calling `bar` automatically would be _wrong_. It's actually a function which accepts a state and returns a new state + value (which in this case is `Bar`, and we're discarding it by storing it in `_`). If you duplicate the `_ <- bar` line, you'll see that it appends `"bar"` that many times.

Comment: @agreif No, just lazy evaluation. Arguments to functions are never automatically evaluated. This is why, e.g., `const "foo" undefined` does not throw a runtime error.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Not even lazy evaluation. Evaluating `bar` fully would not cause it to run; `foo` has to say how the effects of `bar` are incorporated into `foo`'s effects (basically by where a `... <- bar` line appears). In the OP's version of `foo` it specified that the effects of `bar` should be incorporated "not at all" (by not including a bind with `bar`), and so those effects don't happen. Lazy evaluation *must* give the same result as strict evaluation if both terminate, so it's never the explanation for a change in behavior.